# load external command in the same split after repeating it

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to load some text coming from a command line command into a new vim split. I got this working but if I run the command again it keeps opening new splits.

What I want to achieve is getting this into the same split. How can I do this?

```
nnoremap <leader>q :execute 'new <bar> 0read ! bq query --dry_run --use_legacy_sql=false < ' expand('%')<cr>
```

Comment: close that split, then run again.

Comment: @Kent I know but I want to prevent doing that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using the preview window via the `:pedit` command.

```
nnoremap <leader>q :execute 'pedit <bar> wincmd p <bar> 0read ! bq query --dry_run --use_legacy_sql=false < ' expand('%')<cr>
```

However we can do even better by doing the following:

- Making a "query" operator using `g@` and `'opfunc'`
- A query command (feels very vim-like to do so)
- Using stdin instead of a filename

Example:

```
function! s:query(str)
    pedit [query]
    wincmd p
    setlocal buftype=nofile
    setlocal bufhidden=wipe
    setlocal noswapfile
    %delete _
    call setline(1, systemlist('awk 1', a:str))
endfunction

function! s:query_op(type, ...)
    let selection = &selection
    let &selection = 'inclusive'
    let reg = @@

    if a:0
        normal! gvy
    elseif a:type == 'line'
        normal! '[V']y
    else
        normal! `[v`]y
    endif

    call s:query(@@)

    let &selection = selection
    let @@ = reg
endfunction

command! -range=% Query call s:query(join(getline(<line1>, <line2>), "\n"))
nnoremap \qq :.,.+<c-r>=v:count<cr>Query<cr>
nnoremap \q :set opfunc=<SID>query_op<cr>g@
xnoremap \q :<c-u>call <SID>query_op(visualmode(), 1)<cr>
```

Note: I am using `awk 1` as my "query" command. Change to meet your needs.

For more help see:

```
:h :pedit
:h :windcmd
:h operator
:h g@
:h 'opfunc'
:h systemlist()
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks pretty cool will try the preview window tomorrow and approve your  answer afterwards.Regarding the custom function it might be just be what I needed (but never got done). My vimscript knowledge is very lacking but it's a good starter.

Comment: The preview window works perfectly but I only needed to add a filename after the pedit function because else it would also take the text I used as input.

Comment: I forgot to mention some nice "preview window" mappings you may want to know: `<c-w>P` to go to the preview window and `<c-w>z` to close the preview window. See `:h preview-window` for more.